# SharePoint 2013 - How to copy SharePoint when using Friendly URL's in rich HTML content blocks?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Does anyone know of any best practices for copying a SharePoint system from a development environment to a production environment, when we are using Term Store Management links (friendly URLs), within rich HTML content blocks?

It appears that if you copy a SharePoint content database with rich HTML content blocks that have friendly URLs, from one location to another, the links do not decode correctly in the new environment.  In fact you will see your friendly URL's turn from something like this in your development environment...

```
<a href="http://mysite/custom-url-name">my custom link</a>
```

to this in your production environment...

```
<a href="http://mysite/_layouts/15/FIXUPREDIRECT.ASPX?0000000000000000000000000000.....">my custom link</a>
```

Yup, that's just 100% wrong in every regard.  So with that said, is there a best practice on moving SharePoint and it's services around appropriately so that friendly URL's do not break in rich HTML text editors? If so has it been proven?

**If any top SharePoint 2013 developers are aware that this is an official bug from Microsoft please post that as an answer this way we all know that the issue is coming from this release of SharePoint.**